# Embedding $G$ in its holomorph

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, holomorph

Let $H=G\rtimes \operatorname{Aut}G$ be the holomorph of $G$. Obviously $G$ embeds as $g\mapsto (g,1)$, and this embedding is normal. Composing this with any automorphism of $G$ is also a normal embedding; for the purpose of this question, I am not interested in distinguishing embeddings that only differ by an automorphism of $G$.

$G$ also embeds as $g\mapsto (g^{-1},\rho_g)$, where $\rho_g$ is conjugation by $g$, and this embedding is also normal. If and only if $G$ is abelian, $\rho_g=1,\forall g$, and the two embeddings become the same up to the automorphism $g\mapsto g^{-1}$.

What I am generally interested in is - are there other embeddings? Other normal embeddings? Are there any other "canonical" normal embeddings?

But this is a little soft, so let me ask a much more circumscribed question:

> Let $H = Q_8\rtimes \operatorname{Aut}Q_8$, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group. What are all the embeddings of $Q_8$ in $H$? Which are normal?

Comment: Checking with GAP, in the holomorph of dihedral group $D_{16}$ there are four normal subgroups isomorphic to $D_{16}$. Also it is possible that $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \cong G$, in which you get another embedding

Comment: Or just having $Z(G) = 1$ gives you an embedding of $G$ into $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$

Comment: @spin - yes, true, if $\operatorname{Aut}G \hookrightarrow G$, there will be lots of embeddings, at least $|G|$ many conjugate embeddings (which therefore won't be normal); the holomorph has a natural transitive action on the set of elements of $G$, with the $G$ factor acting by translations and the $\operatorname{Aut}G$ factor acting in the obvious way; the stabilizer of any element of $G$ for this action is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}G$.

Comment: Highly relevant is this paper of Cindy Tsang: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.08513.pdf (and the references therein). The question (at least of finding all the embeddings that are normal in the holomorph) appears to be the subject of a line of research initiated by G. A. Miller in 1908 but barely touched until recently.